# Displaying WPDB error in try catch not working?

Tags: php

I am trying to create a Class that will be using a external api and wpdb class however i am having issues already in the try catch block please confirm the below is correct:

```
<?php
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-config.php' );
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-includes/wp-db.php' );

class LoLApi
{
  private $database;

  public function __construct()
  {
    try {
      $this->database = new wpdb('user', 'pass', 'table', '127.0.0.1');
      $this->database->show_errors();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      return $e->getMessage();
    }
  }

}

?>
```

in the other page:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  require 'includes/lolapi.class.php';

  $api = new LoLApi;
  exit();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking instead whether it returns a WP_Error object. If the WP_Error class doesn't exist it will just die and dump an error message. Nowhere does it actually throw an exception.

If you include wp-load.php you'll have the WP_Error class available and you can check for it in the data returned. You could also extend the wpdb class and override the db_connect method to throw a proper exception instead of killing the script on a connection failure.